Azure Functions in a Container: 0 functions found
How do I get Azure Functions to correctly run my .NET function from a container?
Example repo that reproduces the concern: https://github.com/robrich/azure-functions
Public image built from the code above: robrich.azurecr.io/func1:0cc2c12e5da12319faf50750783063130c4daf35-main
I've run the tutorial from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-custom-container using the Azure Functions section.  This builds the C# function and the Dockerfile in Visual Studio 2022.
I provision the Azure Function in the portal using the Consumption plan and choose .NET Isolated 8.0 as my stack.
I've set WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=false to ensure /home/site/wwwroot isn't overwritten with blank content.  See also:

0 function loaded error in Azure app service custom docker container
Running Azure Functions locally shows 1 function found but 0 loaded and it doesn't work
https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-docker/issues/642

Then I follow the instructions from https://github.com/Azure/functions-container-action to add the GitHub Actions build and deploy.  See https://github.com/robrich/azure-functions/blob/main/.github/workflows/dotnet-build.yaml
When I build and deploy the container locally, the function runs just fine, and I get this console output:
info: Host.Startup[326]
      Reading functions metadata (Custom)
info: Host.Startup[327]
      0 functions found (Custom)
info: Host.Startup[315]
      1 functions loaded
info: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Workers.Rpc.RpcFunctionInvocationDispatcher[0]
      Worker process started and initialized.
info: Host.Startup[0]
      Generating 1 job function(s)
info: Host.Startup[0]
      Found the following functions:
      Host.Functions.Function1

When GitHub Actions deploys the container runs in Azure, the function is unavailable and I get this console output:
2024-12-07T02:29:47Z   [Information]   Loading functions metadata
2024-12-07T02:29:47Z   [Information]   Reading functions metadata (Custom)
2024-12-07T02:29:47Z   [Information]   0 functions found (Custom)
2024-12-07T02:29:47Z   [Information]   0 functions loaded

How do I get Azure Functions to correctly run my .NET function from a container?

It turns out that only the Premium or better Azure Function plan supports running in a container. If you use the Consumption plan, you don't get the option to "Deploy as Container Image".  Without this option set (even if all the environment variables are set) it won't correctly start the container, and it'll error with 0 functions found.  Flip over to a Premium or better plan, set the option "Deploy as Container Image" and everything works just fine.
In the Azure Portal, when creating an Azure Function, this question is only present when creating a function on the Premium and better plans:

Without setting this question to "Container Image", the function deploys correctly via GitHub Actions, but does not start, noting 0 functions found.
Switch to the Premium plan and everything starts up just fine.


I've faced the same problem. Locally, with Azure Functions Core Tools I could upload the functions without any problem. But deploying with Github Actions just won't work. I didn't solve it to that time. But here is a similar issue on Github, worth a look: https://github.com/Azure/functions-action/issues/192#issuecomment-1782920933
Let me know if this works for you!

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I'm intrigued. https://github.com/Azure/functions-action deploys a zip file and runs in their container on Linux. By contrast https://github.com/Azure/functions-container-action deploys in my container. I debate running the former then the latter so if it pulls in a zip, it pulls in the zip I want? This seems unintuitive though.
